# What is the difference between currentprovider and givenprovider in web3.js

Tags: ethereum, web3js

Can anyone explain what is the difference between currentprovider and givenprovider?

I think like this.
`givenprovider` connects to blockchain thorough web browser, and
`currentprovider` connects to blockchain thorough metamask.

I'm not sure my understanding is correct.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's a lot of confusion regarding the Ethereum providers because lack of the standard at the begining. I'd like to sort it out as I understand it.

From web3 docs:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

// "Web3.providers.givenProvider" will be set if in an Ethereum supported browser.
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'ws://some.local-or-remote.node:8546', net, options);
```

Please not that to initialise `web3` instance, the `givenProvider` on the `Web3` module is used.

Let's see MetaMask docs:

> MetaMask injects a global API into websites visited by its users at
>   window.ethereum (Also available at window.web3.currentProvider for
>   legacy reasons)

This is based on [ERC1193](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1193.md)

Basically, `Web3` assigns `window.ethereum` to `Web3.givenProvider` property if the provider is ERC1193 compliant (as MetaMask), and can perform some fuzzy magic to detect the provider if not.

Following this logic, on the instance `web3.currentProvider` is the provider that web3 was initialized with, while `web3.givenProvider` is the provider injected by the environment (like `window.ethereum`). For example:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
export const givenWeb3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider)
givenWeb3.currentProvider === givenWeb3.givenProvider // true

export const externalProvider = new Web3('http://localhost:8545')
externalProvider.currentProvider === externalProvider.givenProvider // false
```

Comment: Thank you!! It takes time for me to understand the difference.